# How to load images from URL using Pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I want to load the images  using Pytorch

I have a dataset of `image_urls` with its corresponding labels(**`offer_id` are labels.**)  [image]

Is there any efficient way of doing it in Pytorch?.

Comment: Do you want to use these images to train your model? If so, you can create your dataset class and store a list of urls in a class variables. 

In the __getitem__ function, you can load the image for a url located at chosen index.

Answer (score 1):

This should work if image url is a public URL using pillow, requests and torch together

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from torchvision.io import read_image
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

url = "https://example.jpg"
image = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)

transform = transforms.Compose([
transforms.PILToTensor()])

torch_image = transform(image)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the requests package:

```py
import requests
from PIL import Image
import io
import cv2
response = requests.get(df1.URL[0]).content
im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may convert your image URLs to files first by downloading them to specific folder representing the label. You will certainly find a way to do so. Then you may do like this to check what you have:

```
%%time
import glob
f=glob.glob('/content/imgs/**/*.png')
print(len(f), f)
```

There is a need to create a image loader that will read the image from disk. In here the `pil_loader`:

```
def pil_loader(path):    
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        img = Image.open(f)
        return img.convert('RGB')


ds = torchvision.datasets.DatasetFolder('/content/imgs', 
                                        loader=pil_loader, 
                                        extensions=('.png'), 
                                        transform=t)

print(ds)
```

You may check how I did that for [Cifar10](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LWV0pGw7gScb2cmcmDlNt7d8Y23PC2C0?usp=sharing#scrollTo=02xOQnphI8Gt).

Check the section "From PNGs to dataset".